# Alternative to QR code for long distance tags readable by computer vision?

Tags: computer-vision, qr-code

I am looking for an alternative to QR tags. The application I am working on requires uniquely identifying an object using computer vision, but the object is placed ~10-15 ft from the camera. At this range, the QR codes would have to be giant, and this is prohibitive for the application. The object may also move a little, so blurring may also be a problem at this range. The constraints are:

1. The tag is placed 10-15ft from the camera.
2. It needs to be read by computer vision - this rules out e.g. RFID.
3. The max. size for the tag is a long skinny rectangle, c.a. 1 inch wide by 15 inches tall. A square QR tag therefore could at most be 1x1 inch, but this is way too small. However the area is big enough that something should be possible here?
4. The tag needs to only differentiate ~100 unique objects. You may suggest just using some computer vision framework, but the objects look identical without tags - think of them as just black boxes - so some tag is needed to differentiate them.

When I think about these constraints, I could imagine a system e.g. of black & white squares arranged vertically, which could somehow be uniquely identified by the camera. A little bit like a QR code, but tailored for this aspect ratio and distance to the camera. However I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something already exists. So - are there QR code alternatives for long range (but lower differentiation) applications?

Thanks

Comment: With a 1:15 aspect ratio, a 1D barcode seems like a better fit.  There are numerous symbologies to choose from - Code39, Code93, Code128 to name a few of the more common ones.

Comment: arucos, or any AR tag. those have a lot fewer bits